# If $P_1,P_2,P_3$ are $p_i$-Sylows then $P_1\cap P_2P_3=\{e\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

> If $P_1,P_2,P_3$ are normal $p_i$-Sylows of a group $G$ ($i=1,2,3$ and $p_i$ distinct primes) then $P_1\cap P_2P_3=\{e\}$.

Every element of $P_1$ has order some $p_1^n$. So I wanted to show every element of $P_2P_3$ can't have order a power of $p_1$ unless it is of course $e$. But what is the order of the elements of $P_2P_3$? I haven't figured it out yet.

Any hints? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: second isomorphism theorem might give you some info on the order of $P_2P_3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the hypothese show that $P_1P_2$ is a sub group, the map from the directe product group $P_1\times P_2$ to $P_1P_2$ that $(x,y)$ associeted $xy$ is surjective and t(also bijective), so $\mid P_1P_2\mid $ is of the form $p_1^np_2^m$, and so Lagrange theorem give the result.